# Banner Timeout Error on SSH Connection in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2, remote-access, phpseclib

I recently downloaded the phpseclib0.3.1 library for PHP which should allow me to connect to my EC2 instances via SSH. However, I'm getting trapped with a "Banner Timeout" error message. When I call:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com',1234);
```

With the first argument being the Public DNS and the second argument being the port associated with the security group (the two correctly match). When this command runs I see the following error message:

```
Notice: Cannot connect to ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Banner timeout in ...\SSH2.php on line 815
```

Which corresponds to:

```
    // on windows this returns a "Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected" error
    // the !count() is done as a workaround for <https://bugs.php.net/42682>
    if (!@stream_select($read, $write, $except, $sec, $usec) && !count($read)) {


        user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Banner timeout"), E_USER_NOTICE);
```

The SSH2.php file can be found from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/. If I'm not able to resolve this issue, what are some alternatives in PHP to connect to an EC2 instance?

Thanks!

Comment: The instance may not be responding to the ssh request. Are you sure that your security group is correctly configured and have you tested that you can access the instance via a regular ssh session?

Comment: I've been able to login to this instance via Remote Desktop, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Remote Desktop over SSH or just Remote Desktop? Assuming you're on windows can you launch puTTy and try with SSH - alternatively, spin up a temporary instance and post the IP and the port and I can test if it is open.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you remove the @ before the stream_select? Do any errors start showing up?

Specifically, I'm wondering if you're getting an error like this:

http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?p=384914#p384914